# Camera freezes when webrtc streaming video on Android

Tags: android, webrtc

i want to stream a one-way webrtc video from sender to receiver.
(sender and receiver also android)

Sender outputs a camera preview screen in SurfaceView.
And when a specific event occurs, it connects to the Signaling Server and creates a peer connection.

when the receiver connects and starts streaming videos, it works fine for about 5 mins and then the camera on Sender freezes.

until Receiver receives video streaming, there is no problem with how long it will take.
(never freezing camera on Sender)

I want to know what kind of things I should check if this problem occurs.
Thank you.

Logcat on Sender

```
2023-05-04 17:07:52.009 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
2023-05-04 17:07:54.010 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
2023-05-04 17:07:55.731 3660-3899/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: sender_surfaceView2: Duration: 4001 ms. Frames received: 120. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 120. Render fps: 30.0. Average render time: 2246 μs. Average swapBuffer time: 1205 μs.
2023-05-04 17:07:56.011 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
2023-05-04 17:07:58.012 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
2023-05-04 17:07:59.733 3660-3899/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: sender_surfaceView2: Duration: 4002 ms. Frames received: 119. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 119. Render fps: 29.7. Average render time: 2045 μs. Average swapBuffer time: 1106 μs.
2023-05-04 17:08:00.013 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
2023-05-04 17:08:02.014 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
2023-05-04 17:08:03.735 3660-3899/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: sender_surfaceView2: Duration: 4001 ms. Frames received: 121. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 121. Render fps: 30.2. Average render time: 2349 μs. Average swapBuffer time: 1262 μs.
2023-05-04 17:08:04.015 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
2023-05-04 17:08:06.017 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
2023-05-04 17:08:07.738 3660-3899/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: sender_surfaceView2: Duration: 4002 ms. Frames received: 80. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 80. Render fps: 20.0. Average render time: 2264 μs. Average swapBuffer time: 919 μs.
2023-05-04 17:08:08.018 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 6.
2023-05-04 17:08:08.084 3660-5024/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/MediaCodec: setCodecState state : 0
2023-05-04 17:08:10.018 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 0.
2023-05-04 17:08:11.743 3660-3899/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: sender_surfaceView2: Duration: 4005 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2023-05-04 17:08:12.019 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 0.
2023-05-04 17:08:12.019 3660-3909/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo E/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraStatistics: Camera freezed.
2023-05-04 17:08:15.749 3660-3899/com.cudo.petservice.gaebayo I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: sender_surfaceView2: Duration: 4005 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Could you also add more information about the device and Android version you are testing this on?